# What's the difference between python's multiprocessing and concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

A simple way of implementing multiprocessing in python is

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def calculate(number):
    return number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.map(calculate, range(4))
```

An alternative implementation based on futures is

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def calculate(number):
    return number

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = executor.map(calculate, range(4))
```

Both alternatives do essentially the same thing, but one striking difference is that we don't have to guard the code with the usual `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. Is this because the implementation of futures takes care of this or us there a different reason?

More broadly, what are the differences between `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures`? When is one preferred over the other?

EDIT:
My initial assumption that the guard `if __name__ == '__main__'` is only necessary for multiprocessing was wrong. Apparently, one needs this guard for both implementations on windows, while it is not necessary on unix systems.

Comment: Erm. I *doubt* that you *don't need* the `if` guard. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) `ProcessPoolExecutor` is built on top of `multiprocessing`, and as such it should suffer the same problem (otherwise the `multiprocessing` documentation would show how to avoid that guard, right?). In fact the example from the documentation **does** use the usual guard.

Comment: You're right. I got confused since it is only necessary on windows, apparently. I must admit that I only tested the futures on mac and thus found that the guard is not necessary. I'll add some note in the question emphasizing this.

Comment: One time I brought down a blade server by forgetting that guard :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776189/concurrent-futures-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3

Comment: Look like prefork model on Unix save you from that bit one should always have that 'if' line. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You actually should use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard with `ProcessPoolExecutor`, too: It's using `multiprocessing.Process` to populate its `Pool` under the covers, just like `multiprocessing.Pool` does, so all the same caveats regarding picklability (especially on Windows), etc. apply.

I believe that `ProcessPoolExecutor` is meant to eventually replace `multiprocessing.Pool`, according to [this statement made by Jesse Noller](http://bugs.python.org/issue9205#msg132661) (a Python core contributor), when asked why Python has both APIs:

> Brian and I need to work on the consolidation we intend(ed) to occur
>   as people got comfortable with the APIs. My eventual goal is to remove
>   anything but the basic multiprocessing.Process/Queue stuff out of MP
>   and into concurrent.* and support threading backends for it.

For now, `ProcessPoolExecutor` is mostly doing the exact same thing as `multiprocessing.Pool` with a simpler (and more limited) API. If you can get away with using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, use that, because I think it's more likely to get enhancements in the long-term. Note that you can use all the helpers from `multiprocessing` with `ProcessPoolExecutor`, like `Lock`, `Queue`, `Manager`, etc., so needing those isn't a reason to use `multiprocessing.Pool`.

There are some notable differences in their APIs and behavior though:

1. If a Process in a `ProcessPoolExecutor` terminates abruptly, [a `BrokenProcessPool` exception is raised](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), aborting any calls waiting for the pool to do work, and preventing new work from being submitted. If the same thing happens to a `multiprocessing.Pool` it will silently replace the process that terminated, but the work that was being done in that process will never be completed, which will likely cause the calling code to hang forever waiting for the work to finish.
2. If you are running Python 3.6 or lower, support for `initializer`/`initargs` is missing from `ProcessPoolExecutor`. [Support for this was only added in 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue21423)).
3. There is no support in `ProcessPoolExecutor` for `maxtasksperchild`.
4. `concurrent.futures` doesn't exist in Python 2.7, unless you manually install the backport.
5. If you're running below Python 3.5, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18671528/2073595), `multiprocessing.Pool.map` outperforms `ProcessPoolExecutor.map`. Note that the performance difference is very small *per work item*, so you'll probably only notice a large performance difference if you're using `map` on a very large iterable. The reason for the performance difference is that `multiprocessing.Pool` will batch the iterable passed to map into chunks, and then pass the chunks to the worker processes, which reduces the overhead of IPC between the parent and children. `ProcessPoolExecutor` always (or by default, starting in 3.5) passes one item from the iterable at a time to the children, which can lead to much slower performance with large iterables, due to the increased IPC overhead. The good news is this issue is fixed in Python 3.5, as the `chunksize` keyword argument has been added to `ProcessPoolExecutor.map`, which can be used to specify a larger chunk size when you know you're dealing with large iterables.  See this [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue11271) for more info.

Comment: From the current [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L173) for ProcessPoolExecutor.map , using the chunksize  > 1, it looks like tuples will be sent to the function so the function needs to be able to handle tuples of items rather than single items. Do you think I interpreted that correctly?

Comment: @wwii The tuple returned by that function is processed by the `_process_chunk` method, which pulls each entry in the tuple out, and passes it to the mapping function the user provided. So the user doesn't have to change anything when they use a chunksize > 1.

Comment: @Jay Nope, both deficiencies have been addressed. `chunksize` was added to `map` in 3.5, and `initializer`/`initargs` was added in 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

`if __name__ == '__main__':` just means that you invoked the script on the command prompt using `python <scriptname.py> [options]` instead of `import <scriptname>` in the python shell.

When you invoke a script from the command prompt, the `__main__` method gets called. In the second block, the

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = executor.map(calculate, range(4))
```

block is executed regardless of whether it was invoked from the command prompt or imported from the shell.

Comment: Actually, one **needs** to protect the `__main__` of a `multiprocessing` script on Windows, as the main body is re-executed in the child processes.

Comment: Aah, in that case I misunderstood the question.