# multiprocessing Pool seems to get stuck for no apparent reason

Tags: python, multithreading, terminal

I have a python script with the following, more or less, code:

```
def some_function():
  pass

class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.pool = mp.Pool(10)
  def do_smth(self):
    self.pool.map(some_function, range(10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cls = SomeClass()
  for _ in range(1000):
    print("*")
    cls.do_smth()
```

the jobs are obviously much more heavy than this, however at some point it just get stuck, in a sense that no error is reported, the terminal signals that the script is still running, but no more "*" are printed, and the CPU manager of my PC reports 3% of CPU usage, so seems like that it just "crashed" without saying nothing to nobody.

For the moment, I this it might be a memory issue (however, during the time it works, RAM stays at 70%), but I have no idea... do you have any idea?

I'm working on a Macbook pro M1 max with 24 GPUs and 32GB of RAM

Comment: What python version?

Comment: You'll need to provide code that reproduces the problem for us. This code is not runnable. If we change *some_function()* to *some_function(n)* then this runs without error in Python 3.11.1 on Xeon. Of course that doesn't mean that there's not a problem in your out-of-date version. Can't see why it could be M1-specific

Comment: @Fred Fair point, If you want I can point to the repository (you will need to install tensorflow to run the code), but it's a pretty basic script

Comment: seems pretty close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115092/occasional-deadlock-in-multiprocessing-pool

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the [`start_method`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) for new processes:

```
mp.set_start_method('spawn')
```

This is the default for macOS on Python 3.8+ but not before, and it was changed due to apparent crashes using `fork` as reported in [this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77906). Apart from that if there's any thread level locking happening it could lead to deadlocks in `fork` mode.

Comment: `python --version -> Python 3.9.15`... and with `python -i` i see this: `multiprocessing.get_start_method() #'spawn'`... I'll still add it to be more explicit and see if makes any difference

Comment: Absent that there's no way to magically debug why your code is getting stuck without a reproducible example.

Comment: Fair point, If you want I can point to the repository (you will need to install tensorflow to run the code), but it's a pretty basic script

Comment: seems pretty close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115092/occasional-deadlock-in-multiprocessing-pool